# Tcl variable existence

Tags: tcl

I need to check if

```
get_property PWROPT_WRITE_MODE_CHANGE_A $obj
```

is set or not. get_property will return me a string if property/attribute PWROPT_WRITE_MODE_CHANGE_A is set on object $obj otherwise return 0.
If I do info exists as below, it will always return me 0 because info exists will check on the return value of get_property PWROPT_WRITE_MODE_CHANGE_A $obj.

```
if { [ info exists [get_property PWROPT_WRITE_MODE_CHANGE_A $var] ] } {

}
```

Any pointers?

Comment: I... don't think you can do that because the value of `get_property PWROPT_WRITE_MODE_CHANGE_A $obj` could be set to virtually _any_ variable name. Why are you trying to do this anyway? Are you perhaps checking if `get_property` has been executed or not?

Comment: What do you do if the value of the property is "0" -- there's no way to distinguish a legitimate value of the string "0" and the "unset value" integer 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if `get_property` gives you *a string* when `PWROPT...` is set for `$obj`, or a *0* when `PWROPT...` is not set, you must check this returned value:

```
if { [get_property PWROPT_WRITE_MODE_CHANGE_A $var] == 0 } {
    ...
}
```

Or I missed something?